# A bug tracker service that can can also handle user feedback and community support?

Tags: webapp-rec

Shipping date for the 1.0 of our product is nearing. It has known issues and missing features, but we'd like to release early, be transparent about missing stuff, and be responsive and prioritised on future developments, driven by user input.

So I'm looking to set up a feature / bug tracker where staff can log issues, post both technical or design progress, and as a side effect, upcoming features are showcased to the public. At the same time, I'd like to allow (non-technical) users to find or log support tickets directly, as well as provide more general input in the form of voting for an exsiting feature request / bug, supplying useful details to help get them done, or submitting new feature requests that will be vetted by the userbase and staff. An added bonus would if the facility can double as a space for community support and help each other, or maybe rave or complain about some aspect of the product, commonly found in the form of phpbb-style forums with many small software companies.

I would like to avoid setting up an 'internet forum', so as to avoid the gradual decay of the signal-to-noise ratio that IMO eventually keels all user forums, and instead go with a facility that somewhat constrains open-ended discussions, so activity is mostly focusing on what is happening to the product, and how the user base collectively prioritises areas of improvement, and not the tone of a certain user in a certain answer, the weather etc. And I'd also like it to be an effective issue tracking system.

I looked at uservoice.com and getsatisfaction.com, but I gather that the feature/bug tracker features are rather weak, and they are more focused on the customer-facing use cases.

Are there any issue tracking or customer support services I should evaluate that handles issue tracking, user input and community support all effectively?

Answer (score 2):

Look no further and try [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/features/) for free for 45 days! It's totally worth it.

Among other things it has:

- Great [Issue and Bug Tracking System](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/features/issue-and-bug-tracking.html)
- Awesome [Customer Support](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/features/customer-support.html)
- [Evidence Based Scheduling](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/features/project-management.html)
- Integrated [Version Control System](http://www.fogcreek.com/kiln/features/source-code-control.html)
- [Joel](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/)
- And many many more cool features and super fast environment.

Whatever questions you have regarding the FogBugz please use their [Customer Support](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/support/). I personally never experienced better customer support by any other company, and they have to be since that is one of their killer features.